# Recaptcha AJAX API widget not displaying in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I’m having trouble getting the Recaptcha widget to appear in IE 8 though its working as expected in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.

I’ve created a feedback form that is loaded via AJAX when the user clicks a link and I’m directly calling the Ajax API to place the recaptcha container (the div is loaded in the /feedback-form/modal page):

```
$(".feedback-link", context)
.after('<div id="feedback-modal"></div>')
.click(function () {
    $("#feedback-modal").load("/feedback-form/modal",function() {
        $("#feedback-container").slideToggle('fast');
        Recaptcha.create(recaptcha_key,"recaptcha_ajax_api_container", { theme: "white", callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field } );
    }            
});
```

The validation and submitting for this is also done through AJAX and is working correctly in everything but IE 8. In IE, the form will not load at all, presumably because of the Javascript error that is throw:

```
“Recaptcha.widget is null or not an object at line 15”
```

Any suggestions for how to proceed or different ways to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW Because recaptcha is loaded via flash it doesn't play well with ajax. I understand some component makers like primefaces who specialize in ajaxifying jsf don't even bother with ajax for their recaptcha based component.